# Change Path to Picture Links in Excel

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have manually pasted a large number of linked pictures into a 2010 Excel spreadsheet using insert picture -> select picture location --> link to file. These pictures are part of a report. I update the pictures using R each quarter, and my report automatically updates. Perfect.

I now need to change the directory where the plots are kept, and need to update the links. As there are around 200 of them (its a big report), I want to do this in VBA. Whilst I can loop through the pictures ok (ActiveSheet.Pictures), I can't seem to find the links/address. Any idea how I can see the underlying file location so I might change it - the reference has to be stored somewhere (note - these don't seem to be stored as hyperlinks).

Comment: While I do not know the answer to your question I am wondering if it wouldn't be easier to copy all the files over (and potentially backup the old picture somewhere else before that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea how I can see the underlying file location so I might change it - the reference has to be stored somewhere

1. Create a new folder
2. Paste a copy of the .xlsx or .xlsm excel file
3. Uncompress the file with a zip tool (i'm using 7-Zip)
4. Delete the .xlsx or .xlsm file (optional)
5. Now we have all the component parts of the original file as plain text xml files and folders
6. Inside the folder xl\drawings\ _rels there are files named as drawing2.xml.rels, drawing3.xml.rels, ...

It seems that each file corresponds to a sheet and stores the paths to images in this format:

Target="file:///C:\Users\myusername\Documents\MyImageFolder\My%20Image%20Name.png"

7. Change the paths with a text editor
8. Compress all the contents of the folder to a .zip
9. Change the extension to the original .xlsx or .xlsm

These steps could be automated with VBA, AutoIt, etc., here some references:

- [An example with AutoIt and 7-zip](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/189003-excel-2007-open-xml-file-change-linked-image-paths/)
- http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007FileFormat.asp
- http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007FileFormat02.asp
- [Ron de Bruin zip examples with VBA](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section7.htm)
- [Read and change multiple XML files in Excel (2007) VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11968572/read-and-change-multiple-xml-files-in-excel-2007-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses the Formula Bar as the link in this case, just the same as it would link between ranges in two different worksheets. When I select a linked picture, the formula below populates in the formula bar:

```
=[TrialWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$C$3:$E$6
```

You can access the Shape's formula using the code below and inserting your picture's specific name:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture Name").Formula = "=[TrialWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$C$4:$E$6"
```

In updating the links, you'll have to change the file path in the formula. This might look like:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture Name").Formula = "='C:\Reports2015\[TrialWB.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C$4:$E$6"
```

changing to

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures("Picture Name").Formula = "='C:\Reports2016\[TrialWB.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C$4:$E$6"
```

This question may be of some further assistance for accessing formulas:
[Excel: create image from cell range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139773/excel-create-image-from-cell-range)

And here's a useful Microsoft page for formula file path editing: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f

Comment: This is not about showing Excel cells as an image in the spreadsheet. It is about external image files linked into the spreadsheet. These don't show anything in the formula bar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as teylyn points out, this doesn't work. The formula bar is blank and further, VBA complains that I cannot set the Formula property of the Picture class. Any other ideas? Doing it manually is an option, but its deeply unsatisfying - these links must be stored somewhere!

Comment: Do the pictures ever change, or is it simply a way to house a bunch of pictures in a spreadsheet? From what I can tell, a "linked picture" refers to a picture of data from another Worksheet, according to Microsoft, which lead to my confustion

Comment: @N1DRR try to delete one of the pictures (or move it to a different file) and see if it goes away in your Excel report. I cannot get an inserted picture to dynamically link to a file.

Comment: If I delete or move one of the picture files I get a red X and the message "The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location". But I can't figure out how to get at the link. What I have been doing is keeping the name the same but changing the pictures each quarter, which in turn updates the spreadsheet when I re-open it. The pictures are .PNG files and for context, they are a map indicating how sales have changed regionally over the quarter. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd record a macro while you make a linked picture and see if that will tell you what variable is setting... Are you able to import a picture and then link it back to the file, or must you do it all at one time with this function? I've been unable to create a linked image as you are describing in Excel 2016

Comment: If you wanted to create a system that was (possibly) more robust, you could write a macro that would ask for a filepath and then find/insert all the pictures from the specified file based on the names. If you saved the report in the same path, it would be quick, and you would also be able to look at historical reports more easily.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Might be a 2010 thing. Just tried to record the macro and vba is using ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filename).select to insert linked pictures. I can write code to loop through the ones in my spreadsheet but I don't know how to reverse the expression to get the filename out so I can change it. I have tried F2 but nothing obvious is coming up for a relevant method for picture. I could do as you mention - which is a reasonable back up plan but feels like there must be a better way out there.