# Embed images previously inserted using Pictures.Insert

Tags: excel, vba, image, embed

I've built a template which helps users insert images.

In VBA I used **Pictures.insert**, however I've subsequently discovered that this method sneakily inserts a LINK to the image by default instead of embedding it. Obviously this means that it cannot be viewed by 3rd parties who are not connected to our network.

So, while I've now fixed the *templates*, there are a couple of hundred files across various folders which have already been set up and filled with linked images.

What *I think* I need is a VBA script which will go through every worksheet in every visible workbook in a chosen folder system and 'convert' all linked images to embedded (nb. some images have been inserted manually so are not linked)

I've consulted my IT contact and searched here and elsewhere online but I can't find a solution.

Does anyone have any thoughts, please?

Simple sample attached.
[ImageLink Excel doc saved on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17m8JaBQbTV7FVcWvWC-zBnzgUfqRi2r5)

---

Here's the code I used to INSERT the image, if it's any help. The logic for generating the URL was handled in the spreadsheet:

```
Sub InsertImage()
' This script inserts the image file referenced by the active cell
' Via https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4212-excel-insert-image-from-url.html

Dim Rng As Range
Dim filenam As String

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Rng = Selection

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("activefile").Value = Rng.Value

filenam = Range("filenurl").Value

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: No offence but if you've "consulted [your] IT VBA specialists" you should have a solution by now. If not, does your company have any openings for a VBA dev who actually knows VBA? :D . Just use the paths in the hyperlinks to import the files.

Comment: VBA expertise is not huge here. There are literally hundreds of files, hence trying to avoid manual option. But thank you.

Comment: Ok, that was flippant, apologies. My point was this is simple and there are many solutions already. Take a look at this for example, it should help: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4212-excel-insert-image-from-url.html

Comment: Ha - np :)

Ref that link: I think it was that piece of code which got me into this mess in the first place.

This is a different requirement: I need to embed previously inserted linked images.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code you used to insert the pictures, and what you've tried to solve your issue? Also, where did the image links come from in the fist place (a generated list perhaps?)

Comment: Added the code, for what it's worth. The image links are generated by user selecting file name from a drop-down menu. This file name is picked up by the script shown above and the Pictures.Insert method used.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any easy way to identify 
 the source of a linked image without dissecting the source XML for the workbook.  Steps here, but it would take some work to automate this... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145369/change-path-to-picture-links-in-excel

Comment: I am beginning to fear this. I was hoping perhaps there might be an 'embedimages=TRUE' parameter for SaveAs, but it seems not.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the inserted images and delete the linked version?

Comment: Thanks – I'll try this later and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the images and replace them with a pasted copy:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Unlink ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

End Sub


Sub Unlink(s)

    Dim t, l, h, w, ws
    With s
        Set ws = .DrawingObject.Parent
        t = .Top
        l = .Left
        h = .Height
        w = .Width
        .Copy
        'might need to adjust the paste format...
        ws.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (PNG)", _
                   Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    End With

    With ws.Shapes(ws.Shapes.Count)
        .Top = t
        .Left = l
        .Height = h
        .Width = w
    End With

End Sub
```